# Run-time error in program

Tags: c, pointers, runtime-error, increment

```
int main()
{
  char *p="abcd";
  while(*p!='\0') ++*p++;
  printf("%s",p);
  return 0;
}
```

I am not able to understand why the code does not run. The problem is in the statement `++*p++`, but what is the problem?

Comment: It might be a good idea to explain what you expect from this program, so that those who write answers can tell you how to fix it.

Comment: i expect the output to be - bcde

Answer (score 1):

`P` points to constant string literal `*p="abcd";`  by doing `++*p++` you are trying to modify string '`"abcd"`', for example `a` in string will be increment to `'b'` because of `++*p` that is undefined behavior (constant string can't change). it may cause a segmentation fault.

```
`++*p++` means `++*p` then `p++`
                 ^
                 | this operation try to modify string constant
```

Comment: next error **would be** you shifts `p` points to '\0' when your `while()` terminates and you are trying to  `printf("%s",p);` that will not print any thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
 char *p="abcd";
```

p is pointing to a readonly segment and you can not increment p as you did here

```
while(*p!='\0') ++*p++;
```

Comment: i didn't get it... why can't i increment p?

Comment: @Ceres111 The statement in the answer is incorrect ... you can increment `p`. What you can't increment is `*p` because, as Uday said, `p` points to read-only memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
//char *p="abcd";//"string" is const char, don't change.
  char str[]="abcd";//is copied, including the '\0' to reserve space
  char *p = str;
  while(*p!='\0') ++*p++;
//printf("%s",p);//address pointing of 'p' has been changed
  printf("%s",str);//display "bcde"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now i get it. This means *p can be incremented, isn't it

Answer (score 0):

```
char *foo = "abcd";
char bar[] = "abcd";
```

Consider the differences between `foo` and `bar`. `foo` is a pointer that's initialised to point to memory reserved for a string literal. `bar` is an array with it's own memory that's initialised to a string literal; it's value is copied from the string literal during initialisation. It is appropriate to modify `bar[0]`, etc, but not `foo[0]`. Hence, you *need* an array declaration.

However, you can't increment an array declaration; That's an operation for pointer variables or integer variables. Additionally, your loop changes where `p` points at, before it's printed, so you need to keep the original location of your string *somewhere*. Hence, you *also need* a pointer, or an integer declaration.

With this in mind, it might seem like a good idea to change your code to something like this:

```
int main()
{
    char str[] = "abcd";

    /* Using a pointer variable: */
    for (char *ptr = str; *ptr != '\0'; ++*ptr++);

    /* Using a size_t variable: */
    for (size_t x = 0; str[x] != '\0'; str[x++]++);

    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```